# Which would be better, "I" or "me" in the following sentence?

Tags: pronouns, subjects, objects, case, causatives

I see generally people use ***I*** for addressing themselves, but some people also use ***me*** in the same sense.

Which is better to use, I or me?

> Let **I** recommend you for this...

or

> Let **me** recommend you for this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is not how to refer to oneself, but which grammatical role *I* or *me* has.

- If you are the subject of the sentence ("the *who?*"), use **I**:

  > **I** will take this.
- If you are the object (the "(to) *whom?*"), use **me**:

  > Let **me** do it.
  >   Give **me** the key.

Answer (score 2):

Whether you use *I* or *me* depends largely on whether you use it as a subject or an object in your sentence. (It's the same for other pronouns.)

- (NOTE: Colloquially, people say *Me and my sister went nuts*, though *My sister and I* would be the norm in more formal writing: *My sister and I attended the same parochial school*. That's why I said *largely* above.)

In your sentence, you need an object of the verb *let*, so you need ***me***:

> *Let **me** recommend you for this ...*

<sup>Also keep in mind that in this pattern, ***Let*** someone **do** something, you use the plain form of the verb; you used *recommend* (not *recommends*) correctly, so maybe you don't have this problem. (Congrats!) -- (Another point that may be worth mentioning is the ***for this ...*** part, which is a bit of a concern, but since you didn't give us a complete sentence, I can't tell whether you use it correctly or not.)</sup>

You can read more about personal pronouns in Wikipedia: [English personal pronouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_personal_pronouns#Table_of_basic_personal_pronouns).

Answer (score 2):

*I* and *me*, both are used to refer to oneself. If a person talks about himself, he uses *I* or *me* depending on the structure of the sentence that he is forming.
So, what's the difference?*I* is a subject pronoun. This means that if you are talking about yourself and you are the subject(the one performing the action referred to) in your sentence, you use *I*.
Example:

> *I am eating breakfast.* (The action is *eating breakfast* and when you're stating *I am eating breakfast*, you are the performer of the action. )

*Me* is an object pronoun. It refers to the person that the action of a verb is being done to, or to whom a preposition refers.
Example:

> *He told me to fetch a glass of water.*
>   (The pronoun is *to* and it's directed towards *me* which is the object in the sentence.)

The confusion occurs in cases like these-

> *John and I went to the market.*

If you're confused about the right word, split the sentence into two.
*John went to the market.*
*I went to the market.*
Combining the two, we get *John and I went to the market* and NOT *John and me went to the market.*. 
The same applies for sentences like 
*This is for you and me.*

In the case that you've provided, it's best to use *me*.

> Let *me* recommend this...

The reason is simple. The implication in this sentence is the same as

*You let me recommend this...*

Since someone is letting you do something(the action of *letting* is directed to the object *i.e* *you*), you must use the pronoun *me*.

Hope that helps!